# Live Chat event for Apple's 'By innovation only' announcement (Fall 2019)

Tags: discussion, chat

### Join us in [Ask Different Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat)

As many of us know, in September most years Apple hosts a press event during which new products are announced. For example, on 12 September 2018 we saw the iPhone XS and XR ranges, and Apple Watch Series 4 among the major announcements.

Apple has just issued invites to this year's event. Once again it'll be held at its [Steve Jobs Theatre](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2017/02/apple-park-opens-to-employees-in-april/) located at the Apple Park 'spaceship' campus!

**This event will be held at 10am on Tuesday 10 September 2019 (Pacific Time).**

Below is part of the invite Apple issued for the event:

[image]

To coincide with this, we're holding a live chat event right here using [Ask Different Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat). Users are invited to join us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat) as the announcements unfold.

**Expected announcements**

- 3 new iPhone models
- Apple Watch Series 5
- iOS 13 release date
- watchOS 6 release date
- macOS Catalina release date

**Rumoured announcements**

- a 16" MacBook Pro model
- a new 10.2" iPad model
- Apple TV+
- Apple Arcade

**Surprise announcements**

- Let's find out together! :)

**Time of Keynote address**

The Keynote address is scheduled for 10am on Tuesday 10 September 2019 (Pacific Time). This equates to:

- **Adelaide** - 2.30am, Wednesday 11 September
- **Amsterdam** - 7.00pm, Tuesday 10 September
- **Auckland** - 5.00am, Wednesday 11 September
- **Beijing** - 1.00am, Wednesday 11 September
- **Berlin** - 7.00pm, Tuesday 10 September
- **Hong Kong** - 1.00am, Wednesday 11 September
- **Jerusalem** - 8.00pm, Tuesday 10 September
- **London** - 6.00pm, Tuesday 10 September
- **Moscow** - 8.00pm, Tuesday 10 September
- **New Delhi** - 10.30pm, Tuesday 10 September
- **New York** - 1.00pm, Tuesday 10 September
- **Paris** - 7.00pm, Tuesday 10 September
- **Perth** - 1.00am, Wednesday 11 September
- **Rio de Janeiro** - 2.00pm, Tuesday 10 September
- **Rome** - 7.00pm, Tuesday 10 September
- **Singapore** - 1.00am, Wednesday 11 September
- **Sydney** - 3.00am, Wednesday 11 September
- **Tokyo** - 2.00am, Wednesday 11 September

[**You can also check your local timezone here**](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=Ask+Different+Live+Chat+Event+-+Apple%27s+%27By+innovation+only%27+event+%28Fall+2019%29&iso=20190910T10&p1=1239).

So, for some of us (me included) it'll be a very late night or a very early morning!

Hope to see you there!